# "Не даром"

Tags: пунктуация

Выделятся ли запятой оборот "не даром" в начале предложения? Например, в таком: "Не даром, пиво было изобретено в Древнем Египте намного раньше вина"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово "не даром" - значит не бесплатно, "недаром" - не зря, не напрасно. Ни в одном, ни в другом значении слово запятой не выделяется.

Answer (score 1):

Предполагаемое дополнение Михаила Лермонтова к ответу Ларf.

"- Скажи-ка, дядя, ведь **не даром**

Москва, спалённая пожаром,

Французу отдана?

Ведь были ж схватки боевые,

Да, говорят, ещё какие.

**Недаром** помнит вся Россия

про день Бородина!"